# How to connect to remote mysql database using php (hosted on dotCloud)

Tags: php, mysqli, remote-server, dotcloud

I am unable to connect to my database residing on dotCloud.  I tried:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
```

and

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
```

and

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($remote_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
```

and

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($remote_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
```

but it fails to connect, and I get "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data."

I retrieve variables dynamically above the mysqli script with the following:

```
$env =  json_decode(file_get_contents("/home/dotcloud/environment.json"));
$db_user = $env->DOTCLOUD_DB_MYSQL_LOGIN;
$db_password = $env->DOTCLOUD_DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD; 
$db_host = $env->DOTCLOUD_DB_MYSQL_HOST;
$db_port = $env->DOTCLOUD_DB_MYSQL_PORT;
$remote_server = '$db_host:$db_port';
//I also define $db_name here
$db_name = 'mydbname';
```

I also have the following code below the mysqli script:

```
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
    $result["status"] = "failed";
    $result["message"] = "Failed to connect to database.";
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit;
} else {
    // Successfully connected!
    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
    echo "<p>Successfully connected!!</p>";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your $db_name variable?

Comment: @Stepo, I edited the code above to show where I define $db_name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong in your code.

**1. Your $remote_server variable is using a single quote**

```
$remote_server = '$db_host:$db_port';
```

This means that $remote_server will not expand the $db_host and $db_port variables. You should use double quotes. If you used the variable as it is, it wouldn't work for you.

```
$remote_server = "$db_host:$db_port";
```

See this page for more info:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

**2. You are not using the mysql port when connecting, which is required on dotCloud since it doesn't run mysql on the standard port of 3306.**

Your code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
```

The correct code, using the variables you already declared above:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port);
```

More info can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

For a complete example, it will look like this.

```
$env =  json_decode(file_get_contents("/home/dotcloud/environment.json"));
$db_user = $env->DOTCLOUD_DB_MYSQL_LOGIN;
$db_password = $env->DOTCLOUD_DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD; 
$db_host = $env->DOTCLOUD_DB_MYSQL_HOST;
$db_port = $env->DOTCLOUD_DB_MYSQL_PORT;
//I also define $db_name here
$db_name = 'mydbname';

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
```

Comment: Perfect.  I needed the right syntax for it.  Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to up vote my answer if you felt it helped you.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course.  I'm still rather new using Stackoverflow. I clicked on the checkmark but didn't realize I could also click on the up arrow. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
try like this: I think it will help you.

$connect = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
if (!$connect) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//echo 'Connected successfully';

$db = mysql_select_db($mysql_database,$connect);

if (!$db) echo"'Could not select database";
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried it and it gave me this error (and the page did not load):  Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

Comment: Outch! **Do not give example using mysql_* please. This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.**

Comment: Are you able to connect to the MySQL host using a MySQL client (SQLYog ,MySQL Workbench, etc)?

Comment: @juanchopx2, I'm not familiar with MySQL client you've mentioned, so I'm not sure how I may go about doing so.

Comment: Maybe you are a "console" material: try to use the terminal to connect to your remote instance: "mysql -h **hostname** -u **username** -p"  The terminal will prompt for the password